# In Vuejs, how to fill value from input box from behind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a project using Vue js and Quasar.

I have an input field that is initialized with 10 zeros that only allows numeric numbers.
If I want to add a number, it should fill it in from behind.

"0000000000" -> fill in 1

"0000000001" -> fill in 2

"0000000012" -> fill in 5

"0000000125" -> delete last character

"0000000012" -> fill in 3

"0000000123"

any ideas how i can achieve this? This is what i have currently:

```
<template>
<div> 
<q-input class="input" v-model="number" outlined label="number"  mask="##########" minLength="10" maxlength="10" @input="onInput"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {

setup() {
const number = ref("0000000000")

}
return {
number
}
}
</script>
```

onInput does nothing so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
mask="#########" fill-mask="0" reverse-fill-mask
```

But it only works well with `maxlength="x"` and `mask="#*(x-1)` ( `mask="#########"`) and does not work with `mask="#*x`

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup () {  
    const number1 = ref(0)
    const number2 = ref('0000000000')
    const onInput = (newVal) => {
      number2.value = ('000000000'+ newVal).slice(-10);
    }
    return { number1, number2, onInput }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.7/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
Standard mask: <br/>
number1: {{number1}}
<q-input class="input" v-model="number1" outlined label="number" mask="##########" fill-mask="0" reverse-fill-mask minLength="10" maxlength="10" @update:model-value="onInput"></q-input><br/>
Custom mask: <br/>
number2: {{number2}}<br/>
<q-input class="input" v-model="number2" outlined label="number" minLength="10"  @update:model-value="onInput"></q-input>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.7/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, didn't realise it was with Quasar. Your solution is better then!

Comment: @Kapcash I like your solution also. Anyway, he will need to combine both, when 10 x '0' is required in the mask.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful. And yes, i do need the 10 x 0 in the mask. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @bea2803 I have updated the code. But it's not easy to achieve. I would say it's a bug of Quasar `<q-input>`

Comment: Quasar GitHub Issue: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/15706

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into my problem. My intented behavior was that if every 0 is filled, u can not enter any more digits, instead u have to delete one or more digits to be able to change the number.

Comment: i fixed my issue using :maxLength="method()" instead of :maxLength=11 where i check if the first digit is "0" and returning 10 if this is not the case, so i can not enter any digits anymore.

Comment: Nice workaround!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to add leading 0 characters until a certain string lenght.

Just update the v-model accordingly whenever it changes.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const counter = ref('')
watch(counter, () => {
  // remove leading 0
  counter.value = counter.value.substring(Array.from(counter.value).findIndex(v => v !== '0'))
  // add leading 0 if necessary
  counter.value = counter.value.padStart(8, '0')
})

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="counter" placeholder="Enter a number">
</template>
```

Here is the [live demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UL1ugzAQfpUrCyBRyFhVEClDh85dvTj4aJDw2bLPtFHEu/cgtFWXDh7u7vvzd8tO3tdzwuw5a2MfRs8QkZM/Khqtd4HhBgGHCj4095cKemd9YjSwwBCchVy4uSJFvaPIck7EGKBbSUWel4o2YrEfKihK6I5wUwTQNIKybkaYUJuR3uGwrndoPespoSj9meuYzpGDgItTCPparym+1e+Qsh5GMq9k8LOYV7MZHroO8kNeSpzNVhvz6wnjAIQ9xqjDVb7C/wfw2ryxDlw8VZumokWeora59yfNycBo/aQZZQJoR5LSYH60zuDUqWxXVBkIqMeLmwwG2b9s5WmgZM/rWdht8yOVLV+p/JVU)